# How do I parse two kinds of numbers with Bison and C++?

Tags: c++, bison

I'm writing a calculator of flowsnake numbers and just stubbed a parser. The program is in C++, and I had to figure out a few details of Bison use with C++ by looking at the generated code. (The calc++ example uses Flex, but I'm not using Flex.) I'm new to Bison. Here's the parser so far:

```
%require "3.2"
%language "c++"

%{
#include "flowsnake.h"
#include "parser.h"
int yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type *val);
%}

%token
  PLUS  "+"
  MINUS "-"
  TIMES "*"
  OVER  "/"
  LPAR  "("
  RPAR  ")"
  PREC "prec"
  INT
  FLOWNUM
;

%%

input:
  %empty
| line input
;

line:
  '\n'
| cmd '\n'
| exp '\n'
;

cmd:
  PREC INT
;

exp:
  FLOWNUM
| exp PLUS exp
;

%%
```

And here are the stub yylex and error functions:

```
int yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type *val)
{
  *val=0;
  return 0;
}

void yy::parser::error(const string &msg)
{
  cerr<<msg<<endl;
}
```

I have to parse two kinds of numbers (eventually three, the third being complex numbers with real and imaginary part): rational integers, which use digits 0-9 and can have a sign but no radix point, and flowsnake numbers, which use digits 0-6 and can have a radix point but no sign. If I say `261+34`, then `261` is a flowsnake number equal to 8 and I'm adding another flowsnake number to it. But if I say `prec 261`, then 261 is in decimal and I'm setting the precision to 261 digits. `28+34` and `prec 26.1` are both invalid, but `26.1+34` and `prec 28` are both valid. How do I write a lexer to lex these numbers?

The code is in https://github.com/phma/flowbound .

Comment: So the problem here is that your lexer depends on your parser state. "261" is either a decimal number or a flowsnake number depending on context. That's not a good situation and I would try to change it if you can. The thing that occurs to me is to change it so that "prec nnn" is a single token detected by the lexer not the parser. Not sure if that is reasonable as there may be more to the grammar than you are explaining here, but something to think about.

Comment: Another way to do it may be for the lexer to return the value of the number interpreted both ways, along with a flag saying which ones are valid. The `prec` command would use the decimal interpretation, whereas the operators would use the flowsnake interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your not very detailed description of the target language, it seems like the scanner doesn't need to know what type of number it is looking at in order to identify the token. (Signs might affect that, but see below.) It might not be able to definitively identify errors, but that doesn't matter for tokenisation. (That's based on the idea that `281+34` is an error. If there were a context in which you might want to decompose it into separate tokens -- say, `2`, `81`, `+`, `34` -- then the following won't apply. But that doesn't seem likely.)

In such a case, the best solution is usually for the lexical scanner to simply identify the string and pass it as such to the parser. The parser can then do whichever conversion is necessary, or issue an error message if the string cannot be converted.

It's true that the scanner could have identified the error if it knew which type of numeric token was expected, and the end result of the architecture I suggest is that erroneous tokens are effectively scanned for errors twice (although the second scan doesn't actually cost much since it will come from a failure to convert). So the errors could have been detected faster. But optimising for errors is practically never an effective optimisation strategy (unless you're writing a linter). The common case is a correct input, and introducing complications in your code to deal with errors "more efficiently" is almost always a false economy.

As you say in a comment, you could also have the scanner do *both* conversions, indicating which ones are valid. Again, this seems like false economy. Only one conversion is actually needed, so in the case that two are possible, one of them is a waste of time. This is particularly true if the conversions are costly.

In the parser, the conversions will be indicated by a unit production, which nicely encapsulates the procedure:

```
cmd:
  "prec" integer

exp:
  flownum
| exp "+" exp

integer:
  INT     { $$ = convert_to_int($1); }

flownum:
  FLOWNUM { $$ = convert_to_flownum($1); }
```

Left out of the above is error reporting. In practice, `convert_to_int` and `convert_to_flownum` would probably have some mechanism to return an error condition, and the parser would check that return.

As noted in passing above, signs could be a problem, since you want integers to be optionally signed. A naïve scanner will always scan a sign as a separate token, which is mostly what you want. However, the above definition of `integer` can easily be extended to allow signed integers:

```
integer:
  INT     { $$ = convert_to_int($1); }
| "+" INT { $$ = convert_to_int($2); }
| "-" INT { $$ = -convert_to_int($2); }
```

Comment: What should `yylex` look like? As I said, I'm new to Bison.

Comment: @PierreAbbat: What's wrong with adapting the flex scanner in calc++?

Comment: It's hard enough to learn one new language at once.

Comment: @PierreAbbat measure your plans by your abilities, not the other way around. Many newbies get discouraged by taking on too much (me too, of course, when I was younger).